# Are browsers still single-thread?

Tags: javascript

I listened to an old lecture from Crockford on Javascript (2006) and he was talking about the model

```
Flow  -> Paint
  ^        | 
  |        v
Script <- Event
```

(a loop involving Flow, paint, event, script ...), saying "because all browsers are single threaded".

So, my question is, are they still single threaded?

And for those who might know, are these video lectures still relevant in terms of what is taught?

Comment: Browsers aren't single threaded, but your script runs in a single runloop.

Comment: What @Ja͢ck said. Each tab gets its own thread. JavaScript runs an Event Loop that listens for callbacks to it saying, HEY I got something for you to do DOM.

Comment: @pmac89: In fact even a single tab can have multiple threads, for everything that works concurrently. One for the DOM, one for reflows and repaints, one for the HTML parser, one for background events, and *one for the script engine* of the main browsing context.

Comment: OH, because from a previous read I read the only one who ran tabs in their own threads is Chrome.

Btw, I think some of you are referring to the inner workings of the browser, I was talking about something else .. more like the reply @Geohut gave.

Sorry if I cant express myself quite right, english its not my native language, So I guess I confuse you !.

Comment: @Ja͢ck absolutely right. I just didn't want to add complexity to the idea of what the OP was trying to understand. Chrome is not the only one anymore, pretty much all modern browsers do this now to increase speed and to Sandbox each tab (and sometimes sandbox even more than just the tab).

Comment: @Bergi, If I understood you correctly, these threads are indipendent from the thread that JavaScript code will be run. For example, the DOM thread will be indipendent from the thread that JS code is being executed, and it is these callbacks that are being queued by the web APIs when a thread action completes (the callbacks will be queued in the JS main thread).

Comment: @TobyHarnish Yes, there's only a single thread working the queue, and any number of threads that can run in parallel to do independent work. Of course, not everything is completely independent of the main browsing context scripting thread, the DOM and layout and painting and HTML parsing threads need to synchronise with each other - to the point where it doesn't make sense to use multiple threads but rather do things in turns on the same thread. But that's where browser engines differ, and the programmers implementing them are free to choose optimisations they find reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes they are still all running single threads in the treatment of generating your page and actions on the front end. There are ways to make it seem like it isn't and run a javascript process independently like a pseudo multi thread using web workers introduced in html5. By pseudo I mean it works like most multi threaded processes it switches so fast between the clock interrupts it seems as if it's multi threaded. More information on web workers can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp as well as google of course.

Comment: Thank you ! "Technically yes they are still all running single threads in the treatment of generating your page and actions on the front end"

This is what I was expecting to know, if the definition/thing crockford said was still accurate !

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the JavaScript you get to run, yes. This is normally not an issue because anything you intend to execute in JavaScript that might take more than a millisecond can be expressed as an "asynchronous" operation (for instance, AJAX requests, animation transitions, etc). That means all your code does is start the operation, and register possible callbacks for it to finish.

There are very infrequent exceptions to that where it makes sense to have a "Web Worker", but I have never actually seen those put to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Browsers are multi-threaded by Design.**

In browsers, normal javascript code is executed by javascript runtime which is single-threaded. But Browsers like chrome use **WEB APIS** which has multiple threads to process blocking operations (such as setTimeout(), DOM, Ajax, etc) **asynchronously** using an event loop.

The browser might be seen as single-threaded because it runs normal javascript code in a single thread but other blocking operations are handled by multiple threads.

**Remember** normal javascript codes are processed in a single thread even if it is blocking like ***forEach()***. If you have a forEach in your program the javascript won't be able to do anything unless the forEach() completes but if you define ***setTimeout()*** then Web API will recognize it and pass it onto the hidden threads hence it will be processed asynchronously.